# magento 2 observer

Tags: magento2

In Magento 2 I'm trying to create an observer.

The objective is to call the method `eventLogging` when click "place order".  To test the method, I send a basic message ("Hello") to a log file.

But nothing seems to happen when I "place order".  What am I doing wrong?

`/var/www/magento2/app/code/Myapp/Order/etc/frontend/events.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Ev    ent/etc/events.xsd">
<event name="checkout_submit_before"">
    <observer name="myapp_controller_success_action" instance="Myapp\Order\Observer\MyappObserver"   />
</event>

</config>
```

`/var/www/magento2/app/code/Myapp/Order/Observer.php`

```
<?php 


namespace Myapp\Order\Observer;

use \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class MyappObserver implements ObserverInterface {
public function __construct(

    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
) {

    $this->logger = $logger;
}
public function eventLogging(\Magento\Framework\Object $observer) {

    $event = $observer->getEvent();
    $quote = $event->getQuote();

    $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/developer.log');
    $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
    $logger->addWriter($writer);
    $logger->info($quote->getData(),true); 
}
public function execute(Observer $observer) {

//  $event = $observer->getEvent();
 //   $quote = $event->getQuote();
        $myfile = fopen("var/log/debug.log", "a+") or die("Unable to open file!");
        fwrite($myfile, "hello");

        fwrite($myfile, print_r($quote->getData(),true));
        fclose($myfile);
              //$event = $observer->getEvent();
              //  $quote = $event->getQuote();
              //  Mage::log(print_r(Zend_Debug::dump($quote->getData()), true),NULL, 'developer.log');
                exit;
            }
            /*public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
                rm_state()->controllerSet($observer['controller_action']);
            }*/
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no declaration of property "logger" in your observer class.

First you have to declare the class property "logger" as protected and then only you can use it(`$this->logger`) in the observer class. Declare it as below before any functions (use underscore to avoid confusion with the function variables):

```
protected $_logger;
```

Now use this property as `$this->_logger` in the constructor.

One more thing if you're using Magento ce-2.0.0 stable version then your coding is incorrect, there is not class/object like `\Magento\Framework\Object` the observer is always and should always be an object of `\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer` only. So change accordingly in `eventLogging` function too.

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: @user20719, if this answer solves your issue, please mark it as accepted, so others can easily resolve this issue when they encounter.

Comment: thanks for you response. Although,  its my understanding to access the "eventLogging" method I need to add method attribute of the event tag in 'events.xml'.  When I do this I get "Invalid XML" message "nvalid XML in file /var/www/magento2/app/code/Myapp/Order/etc/frontend/events.xml:
Element 'observer', attribute 'method': The attribute 'method' is not allowed." What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should implement \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface in your observer and use only method 'executor'. There is no possibility to use attribute 'method'. You can invoke your custom method from the 'execute'

Comment: I am implementing "ObserverInterface" and removed 'method' from events.xml.  But still doesn't call 'execute(Observer $observer)'.  I'm also "listening" to "checkout_submit_before" but tried other "listeners" and none seem to "fire" execute.  Any idea?

Comment: Finally working!!! Thanks all!!  Although not sure what did the trick...I did the following 1) removed "use \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;" and 2) updated the execute method from "(Observer $observer)" to "("\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)".  Then my event fired!  I reversed and seems to fire so not sure why it's working.  
;

Answer (score 1):

Your XML declaration is incorrect: in has an extra double quote in the line:
`<event name="checkout_submit_before"">`
You should use an adequate IDE to detect such errors.

Comment: Thanks but I fixed that and still not working

Answer (score 1):

XSD URI has changed

"../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Event/etc/events.xsd" should be replaced with “urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd”.

Then run "bin/magento dev:urn-catalog:generate .idea/misc.xml" if you use PhpStorm.
Right XSD URI will verify if your event.xml is correct.

Comment: should I still run magento dev:urn-catalog...if I'm using Eclipse with "PHPEclipse"?

Comment: magento dev:urn-catalog is only for PhpStorm.

Comment: You can find a help how to use xml validation in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7489510/disable-xml-validation-in-eclipse