# Magento 2 observer event not triggering

Tags: magento2

I have added this observer to my module and I put event definition in `events.xml`

```
# app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/etc/frontend/events.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_submit_before">
        <observer name="vendor_modulename_order_save_before" instance="Vendor\ModuleName\Observer\OrderObserver" />
    </event>
</config>
```

I have added some logic in my observer

```
# app/code/Vendor/Name/Observer/OrderObserver.php
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class OrderObserver implements ObserverInterface
{

    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    /**
     * @param Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $quote = $observer->getQuote();
        ...
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try with **`events.xml`** file inside etc folder remove from frontend folder,

```
# app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/etc/events.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_submit_before">
        <observer name="vendor_modulename_order_save_before" instance="Vendor\ModuleName\Observer\OrderObserver" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Comment: But it will trigger for all areas, we need for Frontend... here area specific is not working.. is this magento issue.

Answer (score 2):

Try placing your `events.xml` file under `webapi_rest` like this

```
app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/etc/webapi_rest/events.xml
```

as most of the checkout is executed via ajax calls to the REST Api.

Answer (score 1):

You must specify method name in name field as name="methodname".

Comment: As I read, this was only in beta version. Now it is always execute method

Comment: ok, if not visited once try to visit this link. If could be helpful here @ http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92927/magento-2-observer or you can also visit @ https://community.magento.com/t5/Programming-Questions/magento-2-observer/td-p/23627

Comment: not that helpful but thanks